# Is there any specific way to set padding and margins?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in CSS and I wanted to test my skills, so I took up some projects to build basic websites purely from css and html. However I often got stuck in places, especially when setting up margins, padding, height etc.

How do I determine the exact values of the margin, padding etc.? Is there some mathematical calculation that people do or do you just put in random values and check if they work?

**Answer**
So, a couple of things I think should be followed when setting paddings/margins:

- use values such as percentages(%), rems, ems and other responsive values to make sure you're not creating a page with fixed pixels which overflow on mobile devices. You can check this [link](https://dev.to/promhize/completely-responsive-css-values-no-not-media-queries-d4l)
- understand how box-models work, since they are essential for working with margins and stuff. Here is a diagram for better understanding. Even the dev tools of most browsers show the box model of the selected element.
  [image]
- it's worth learning about flex/grid (at least it helped me out a lot), because they make creating layouts so much more easier.

- `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` may be useful on their own too - you don't have to automatically set all margins.
- I tried this out and it really, really helps: make a design or layout of the entire website before writing code. Many people have a designer, so that's great but I often just went on writing different values for margins and padding, hoping one of the values would work. So, making a layout before writing code might be helpful.

Comment: If you are doing a lot with px values you may be creating non responsive pages. It’s worth finding out about things like  flex/grid and using relative units for many things.

Comment: I've been learning flex for sometime now, there's always some attribute i never knew that solves the problem, but i have to search for hours to fix it. But thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ideas that might be helpful.

- `margin: auto` -> this can help you quickly center an element without too much hassle
- flex and grids -> [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70804222/14121581) might provide some useful links
- check out different [CSS units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) -> [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36876937/14121581) gives a nice, brief overview
- this might be beyond what you need, but if you need to do a calculation in CSS, there's [a function for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) -> `calc()`

Edit: `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` may be useful on their own too - you don't have to automatically set all margins.

Comment: than you about the margin part, it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

People use graphic site designs and build css based on them.
Margin and padding are usually set in bulk for the tag.
A good example might be material design

I recommend using the already mentioned

- flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: thank you so much!